# Can cudaMalloc (not cudaMallocManaged) use system RAM instead of the GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have an application that uses a lot of GPU memory.  It was written with a cudaMalloc() call, with the intention that it might fail on GPUs that didn't have enough memory, and then something else would happen.  However, recently this architecture failed me, because I apparently successfully allocated 30GB memory on a 24GB card!  As best I can tell, it was actually allocating RAM (Windows Task Manager would show RAM usage going up at the same time).  Is this a documented feature?  The graphics card is certainly new enough to support the Unified Memory Model, but I expected that I'd need to use cudaMallocManaged() to leverage it, and that cudaMalloc() would go to the GPU.  As it happens, for my application I'd much rather fail early and alert the user that they don't have a large enough GPU, vs. trying to use system RAM, so I'm trying to force the allocation to go to the GPU or fail.

In more details: I installed a 24GB GPU (NVidia GeForce RTX 4090) on a computer with the latest Windows 10 and latest NVidia drivers, and an AMD processor.  Then I called cudaMalloc(30000000000).

Expected: return status of "insufficient memory", and no memory allocated.
Observed: return status of "success", and system RAM usage bumps up.

I've seen it behave as expected with the same graphics card on a different computer, which had an older version of Windows and an older driver and an Intel processor.  I'm aware that this is several differences, any one of which could be responsible for the new behavior.  However, the new behavior was completely unexpected to me, so I'm asking if anyone has seen cudaMalloc (not cudaMallocManaged) behave like this, silently allocating system RAM instead of GPU memory, in any circumstances at all.

Comment: One Windows, it is the host display manager which manages GPU memory and not the driver, so this virtualisation of memory is probably a Windows feature

Comment: Yes, this is [expected behavior](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/virtual-memory-paging-support-for-pascal-gpus-on-windows-10-with-wddm-2-0-model/56347) in some situations, on Windows WDDM. If you don't like this behavior, and your GPU is capable of being switched to TCC mode (not applicable to RTX 4090), then you can stop windows from doing what it wants to do by switching to TCC mode.  Otherwise, WDDM is in direct control of GPU memory, not CUDA.

Comment: Holy cow! I knew I hated WDDM, I didn't know I hated it this much!  Robert, do you want to move your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it as such?

Comment: Also, follow-up question: I would really like my memory to just get allocated on the GPU, and to tell me if I try to cudaMalloc() memory I don't have. What's the best way of making this happen? The reason I ask is that, if I ask, WDDM will say that only 81% of the GPU is available (cf. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/413584-matlab-is-able-to-utilize-only-a-part-of-actual-available-vram); in the past, my impression was that if I just started grabbing, I could at least get up to 90%.